# Filter circuit design for input: pair of positive and negative pulses and output: digital High

Tags: filter

I am working with an IR sensor which gives the following output once the sensor is actuated. The sensor creates a negative pulse followed by a positive pulse. The pulses each are approximately 10 ms wide. These pulses are approximately 1 sec apart. Two pulses constitute one single output event.

I am reading this signal in LabVIEW cDAQ device using an analog voltage input module. My goal is to drive a digital output high in LabVIEW software when the event occurs (at the end of positive pulse). Another way to say is I want to completely ignore all negative going pulses and overshoots and I only want to observe the first positive going pulse. Once observed I want to drive a digital output high in LabVIEW.

I don't have good knowledge in signal processing. My thought is I need to filter out the negative pulse and overshoots. Then I can use filter to detect the positive pulse and drive a digital output high. I want to leverage the signal processing tools in LabVIEW but I don't know how to design filter circuit.

I would appreciate any direction on how to design the circuit with the help of LabVIEW signal processing tools. Thank you so much!

[image: Negative and positive pulses with overshoot]

Comment: You have two pulses but you want one spike? What is the scale of the time axis?  When should the spike occur relative to the pulses? How much delay can you tolerate? What is the maximum positive ringing of the negative pulse?

Comment: Looks almost like a 5 V square wave put through a differentiator (capacitor.) Why can't you just work backward in the chain to get access to the earlier square wave and use that (or invert it?) Or do you have any access before this signal? What voltage levels are you looking for in the output? What current compliance does it need to provide? Finally, what's the period between them and how wide are those narrow pulses?

Comment: Thanks for your questions. @Elliot: I want to create a positive spike from the second positive pulse and filter out the rest. The pulses are approximately 10 ms wide. The pulse should occur during the positive pulse. Maximum positive ringing of negative pulse is above 7 V.

Comment: You should try to solve the problem yourself before posting a question here.

Comment: @jonk: What do you mean by working backward in the chain? I am getting this a signal as an output from an IR sensor. I don't have any access before this signal. I am looking for voltage level above 5V. I need to create a trigger from this train of pulses. I need to create the trigger in LabVIEW using signal processing tools so current compliance is not an issue. The narrow pulses are 10 ms wide and period between them is around 1 sec.

Comment: @Drew: I am new to signal processing. I am working on the solution and seeking help here to better understand. Thanks.

Comment: @user141512 You should write up a lot more in your question, itself. Include what has been written as comments. (It's not fair to make everyone read all the comments to understand the question.) And I am still confused. Do I gather correctly that you want to completely ignore all negative-going pulses and that you ONLY want to observe the first positive-going pulse and that you want to block "the rest?" At what exact point is "the rest" complete? Do you have a reset signal to restart the circuit? Or is there a "long time" after which an automatic reset should take place?

Comment: @Jonk I am sorry I did a poor job explaining the question. I am rewriting it and incorporating answer to your questions. Thanks!

Comment: @jonk I edited the question. Please let me know if you have more questions. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: @user141512 It's a labview question now. I have no experience with labview.

Comment: @jonk: apart from lanview, do you have any insight from an electrical engineering point of view?

Comment: @user141512 Yeah. It looks like one BJT, some resistors, and a pair of NAND gates. But I also think you need a way to reset it once it locks up from the positive pulse. Also, the complexity depends a little on how focused you are on getting a signal ONLY at the falling edge of the first positive pulse or if the rising edge would be fine.

Comment: Hi jonk, the solution can be simpler I guess. Rising edge will be fine. Can you please explain more?

Comment: @user141512 It would involve a simple [SR FF](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Digital/dig52.php) make from two NAND gates; a way to guarantee the SR FF is initialized into one pre-latching state; and a way to latch the SR FF on the rising edge of the first positive going pulse (two resistors and one BJT.) Once latched, there's no way to reset it back. So it stays "forever after" once latched.

Comment: @Jonk thank you! yes, I realized implementing a positive edge trigger flip flop can solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A positive edge trigger SR flip-flop can solve the problem. For Reset input providing a 0 and for S input providing the signal which resembles a clock signal. Q will toggle to 1 for positive edge of the clock input.